# str.split is not a function error in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I keep getting an error when I input the following into Sublime:

```js
function longestWord(str) {
  var result = str[0];
  str = str.split(' ');

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].length > result.length) {
      result = str[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var sentence = ["the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."];

console.log(longestWord(sentence));
```

I get an Uncaught TypeError: str.split is not a function(...)

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" --- you're trying to invoke something that is not a function.

Comment: what do you pass in as `str`?

Comment: What is `str`? Give an example as to how you're calling `longestWord('what are you passing here?')`

Comment: var sentence = ["the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."]

Comment: This function is supposed to return the longest word in an sentence/array.

Comment: Why are you passing an array to the function when it expects a string?

Comment: @Mike - That's the kind of info that would be rather helpful up front, FYI.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are passing an argument of an array of one string into your function, rather than just passing in your string.

Also note that there's nearly always a better way than using a for-loop. [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is for traversing  an array and returning a single value:

```js
  
var longest = function(str){
    return str.split(' ').reduce(function(long, cur){
        return cur.length > long.length ? cur : long;
    }, '');
};

var str = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
console.log(longest(str));
```

Notice you don't have to manually keep track of an index, create temporary variables, or manually extract data from the array. Once you get used to `reduce` it can make your code clearer and help prevent mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

```
          function longestWord(str) {
             var result = str[0];
             str = str.split(' ');

              for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
                 if (str[i].length > result.length) {
                     result = str[i];
                 }
            }
           return result;
       }
        var sentence = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
       document.write(longestWord(sentence));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to split a array, not a string. The below code is corrected.

```
function longestWord(str){
    var result = str[0];
    str = **result**.split(' ');

    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(str[i].length > result.length){
            result = str[i];
        } 
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to change the value that is passed instead. Having the function accept an array with a single element seems unreasonable.

Comment: You need a `var longest='';` and compare with that. `str[i]` can never be longer than `result` as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more functional approach that's a bit more reader-friendly.

```js
function getLargestWord(stringOrArray){
  var words = stringOrArray.toString().match(/\w+/gi); //toString..ifs its an array otherwise dont need it
  var wordLength = words.map((e ,i) => i = e.length);
  var highestNumber = Math.max.apply(null,wordLength);
  
  return words[wordLength.indexOf(highestNumber)];
}
var sentence = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
console.log(getLargestWord(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same longest word challenge and I didn't find a simple way out so I created a method to split a sentence into an array, since str.split() didn't work on that particular platform.

```
function splitArray(sentence){
  var arrayPosition = 0;
  var oneWord = "";
  var newSentence = sentence + " ";
  var splitArray = new Array();
for(var j = 0; j < newSentence.length; j++){
  if(newSentence[j] === " "){
      splitArray.push(oneWord);
      arrayPosition++;
      oneWord = "";
  }else{
    if(!isNaN(newSentence[j])){
        //don't add to the string
    }else{
        oneWord += newSentence[j];
    }
  }
}
return splitArray;

};
```

This function returns an array each word in the sentence passed in and doesn't take integers as character or string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to split an array.

Instead pass a string.

```
function longestWord(str) {
    var result = str[0];
    str = str.split(' ');

    for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i].length > result.length) {
            result = str[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var sentence = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
document.write(longestWord(sentence));
```